# Tokenizing SQL Injection strings

Tags: r, tokenize

I have a data set of requests obtained from numerous PCAP files and have loaded these PCAP files into R. Each PCAP file effectively refers to a single observation (row).

In this data set there is a "Request" column that gives a string regarding the request of the source. For example a request may read:

```
http://111.22.33.1/ilove/usingR/extraextra/sqli/?id='or1=1--
```

I want to tokenize each request string in order to run some machine learning algorithm on it. What would be the best way to tokenize strings like these in order to run some analysis on it? I know packages such as `tm` exist, but have had little experience with them.

Comment: take a look at the `urltools` package and if there is any deficiency in the parsing tools there let me know what you need augmented.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific giving actual inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that you have first to examine your request variable and find similar patterns to help you find rules to tokenize your variable.

Then you could use `str_split`with the `/` pattern. If you keep the apparition number in the string, some models may find you the co-occurrence patterns in your requests.

Then do some analysis, like frequency check, for ip address and for the text.

tm is more for text corpus. Here, as it is "automated" created string, you probably could find some useful information with more classical methods first.